# hash function for every data type

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, hashtable, unordered-map

On my data structures class i have to implement an hash table. I managed to implement the hash function like this:

```
size_t hashFunction(const string &key)
    {
        size_t h = 37;
        for (char c: key)
        {
            h = (h * 54059) ^ (c * 76963);
        }
        return h % 86969 % buckets;
    }
template<class T>
size_t hashFunction(const T &key)
    {
        return ((key * 54059) ^ (key * 76963)) % 86969 % buckets;
    }
```

but my teacher only wants me to have a single hash function for every data type, how can i achieve that?

Comment: That's impossible. Either you or your teacher must have misunderstood something.

Comment: It could be possible if you treat the key as an array of bytes, and hash using the byte contents of the key. ***But*** for objects containing pointers (like `std::string`) that makes no sense as you only hash the object itself (including the pointers) but not the data the pointers are actually pointing to. That's why [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) have so many specializations.

Comment: Even treating the object as an array of bytes won't necessarily work, because the compiler can add padding inside the object, and the bytes in the pad won't necessarily have the same value for two objects that otherwise compare equal.

Comment: This is a _talk with your teacher_ moment.  A hash function should return the same hash for two objects that compare equal.  Your two-function solution would work correctly for integer types, std::string, and certain other types.  No single function would work for "every data type".  Perhaps your teacher only wants to hash integers or other certain types?  Anyone asking for "a single hash function for every data type" should be told "That can not be done."

Comment: @PeteBecker Furthermore, it won't work because types with internal pointers can have different bytes despite comparing equal.

Comment: msvc (and recent gcc + clang now too) have an option to initialize padding to prevent data from leaking. Not sure if that's on the stack only. But with that option a generic `hash()` would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one that works with all types:

```
template<class T>
std::size_t hashFunction(const T&)
{
    return 0;
}
```

It isn't very good and I wouldn't recommend using it for anything. But it achieves the goal of working with all types.

You can get better hashing with type specific hash functions, which I would recommend doing.

Comment: goes perfectly with the ideal [random number generator](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: Here is a better one that is 100% collision free: `template<class T> const T& hashFunction(const T& t) { return t; }`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow does it work for std::string?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Sure. It's the identity function.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow A hash function should return some kind of integer.